# reactivex repeated skip between

Tags: reactive-programming, reactivex

Suppose I have the following stream of data:

```
1, 2, 3, a, 5, 6, b, 7, 8, a, 10, 11, b, 12, 13, ...
```

I want to filter everything between 'a' and 'b' (inclusive) no matter how many times they appear.  So the result of the above would be:

```
1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 12, 13, ...
```

How can I do this with ReactiveX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use scan with initial value `b` to turn

`1, 2, 3, a, 5, 6, b, 7, 8, a, 10, 11, b, 12, 13, ...`

into

`b, 1, 2, 3, a, a, a, b, 7, 8, a, a, a, b, 12, 13, ...`

and then filter out `a` and `b` to get

`1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 12, 13, ...`

In pseudo code

`values.scan('b', (s, v) -> if (v == 'a' || v == 'b' || s != 'a') v else s).
    filter(v -> v != 'a' && v != 'b');`

Comment: Outstanding.  I completely missed the use of Scan for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  I'm posting this in case anyone else needs an answer to it.  A slightly different setup than I described above just to make it easier to understand.

```
List<String> values = new List<string>()
{
    "1", "2", "3",
    "a", "5", "6", "b", 
    "8", "9", "10", "11",
    "a", "13", "14", "b",
    "16", "17", "18", "19",
    "a", "21", "22", "b",
    "24"
};

var aa = 
    // Create an array of CSV strings split on the terminal sigil value
    String.Join(",", values.ToArray())
    .Split(new String[] { "b," }, StringSplitOptions.None)

    // Create the observable from this array of CSV strings
    .ToObservable()

    // Now create an Observable from each element, splitting it up again
    // It is no longer a CSV string but the original elements up to each terminal value
    .Select(s => s.Split(',').ToObservable()
        // From each value in each observable take those elements
        // up to the initial sigil
        .TakeWhile(s1 => !s1.Equals("a")))

    // Concat the output of each individual Observable - in order
    // SelectMany won't work here since it could interleave the
    // output of the different Observables created above.
    .Concat();

aa.Subscribe(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```

This prints out:

```
1
2
3
8
9
10
11
16
17
18
19
24
```

It is a bit more convoluted than I wanted but it works.

**Edit 6/3/17:**

I actually found a cleaner solution for my case.

```
List<String> values = new List<string>()
{
    "1", "2", "3",
    "a", "5", "6", "b", 
    "8", "9", "10", "11",
    "a", "13", "14", "b",
    "16", "17", "18", "19",
    "a", "21", "22", "b",
    "24"
};

string lazyABPattern = @"a.*?b";
Regex abRegex = new Regex(lazyABPattern);

var bb = values.ToObservable()
    .Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + "," + s2)
    .Select(s => abRegex.Replace(s, ""))
    .Select(s => s.Split(',').ToObservable())
    .Concat();
bb.Subscribe(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```

The code is simpler which makes it easier to follow (even though it uses regexes).

The problem here is that it still isn't really a general solution to the problem of removing '*repeated regions*' of a data stream.  It relies on converting the stream to a single string, operating on the string, then converting it back to some other form.  If anyone has any ideas on how to approach this in a general way I would love to hear about it.